Jenkins not updating the polling configuration
I've Jenkins 2.462.3 with a normal job.
When I try to change the additional behaviours to exclude a path it just doesn't work even if I save/apply. It runs the old configuration and it doesn't exclude the path.
Right now the only solution I found is to recreate the job (which works without any changes).
Then if I try to change to a new path in the recreated job. Again it doesn't work and I need to recreate again.
Any solution?

Jenkins does have a problem where it doesn't immediately pick up configuration changes. In my experience it manages to catch the changes from the second time onwards. Is that not sufficient?

I tried to run manually the job and doing multiple pushes (to see if it gets the new configuration) and nothing worked.
